# Calculation of a power series sum

Tags: power-series

How can I calculate the following sum:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (n+2)x^n$$

What is wrong with spreading it to:  $2x^n + nx^n$?   both I know how to calculate.
Thank you

Comment: There is nothing wrong with that once you know that the sum converges, which it does if and only if $|x|<1$.

Comment: Compare with $$\frac1{x^2}\sum \frac{d (x^{n+2})}{dx}$$

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong. You can use it.

Answer (score 0):

You're absolutely right... as long as you know you're using *convergent* series !